# Forçar abertura de link em navegador mobile e não no facebook?

Tags: mobile, facebook, navegador-de-internet, link

Ao compartilhar o link de uma página no facebook seja por messenger ou em algum post quando o usuário clicar, o mesmo será aberto no navegador do próprio facebook, que por sua vez está dando alguns bugs "esquisitos" na minha página, sendo que a mesma no chrome e no firefox funciona perfeitamente bem, então eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de detectar e forçar a abertura do link no navegador do celular e não no facebook?

Este é o código para detectar se é o navegador do facebook ou não

```
function faceApp() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);
}
```

Eu tentei abrir o navegador externo assim e não funcionou

```
navigator.app.loadUrl('http://m.site.com', { openExternal:true });
```

E também testei esse aqui, mas também não funcionou

```
window.open('http://m.site.com', '_system');
```

Comment: É possível. O UOL faz isso. Eu também quero descobrir como. O Navegador do Facebook dá uns bugs nos meus códigos JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazendo isso você está, de certa forma burlando as permissões do usuário porque a configuração do browser depende exclusivamente dele. Essa configuração é interna dentro do app do Facebook.

O que você pode fazer é exibir uma mensagem que se comporta melhor abrindo no chrome e só exibir o conteúdo no mesmo, nada mais.

Comment: Atualmente já exibo uma mensagem avisando sobre a experiência de navegação no navegador, mas eu gostaria de poder redirecionar direto para o navegador, como sei que é possível abrir apps através de links achei que fosse possível fazer isso também

Comment: Mas nesses casos, você terá que trabalhar com Dynamic Links e trabalhar o app para "escutar" esse link. O que não é o caso pois você não conseguirá modificar o navegador

Comment: Vou manter o aviso então, se fosse possível pelo ao menos criar um botão para tal, acho um pouco constringente a pessoa abrir o link e pedir pra ele abrir pelo navegador.